# Is there any built-in Math method in js that unifies 0 (zero)

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, zero

I need something that is behaving like this

```js
const unifyZero = n => {
  if (n === -0) return 0;
  return n;
};
```

Comment: aren't them the same thing??? -0 === 0

Comment: My math teachers didn't taught me well, none of them taught me about -0 or at least on that linear scale of going to the right of zero for positive and going to the left of zero for negative.

Comment: What is the real reason you need this? Is this for rounding?

Comment: @epascarello The reason why I need this is complex number conjugate calculation.
I wanted to make solution very clear.
https://exercism.io/tracks/javascript/exercises/complex-numbers/solutions/96492f0538da4d18bf9c640a544f0c8c

Comment: @Marcos they are not the same in float representation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: Are you sure you want -0 to become 0? Signed zero was introduced to handle things like branch cuts correctly. EDIT: Never mind, branch cut isn't an issue for complex conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `0` to the value:

```
var n = -0;
console.log(n);     // outputs -0
console.log(n + 0); // outputs 0
```

Comment: Thanks!
But still if i left something like that in code:
`-a + 0` someone else may remove that + 0
But thanks a lot for that trick!

Comment: @gkucmierz: Add a comment to the line to make clear what you're doing? JS is weird, floating point is weird, sometimes you gotta be weird with 'em.